# Kotlin class on eclipse acting weird, every time I run the program I am getting output from other file

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

```
class DemoFunction {

    fun sum(x: Int, y: Int) : Int {
        return x + y;
    }

    fun diff(a : Float, b: Float) : Float {
        if(a >= b)
            return a - b;
        else
            return 0.0F;
    }


    // main fun
    fun main(args : Array<String>) {
        println("Sum of 10 & 20 = " + sum(3, 5))
        println("Difference of 30 & 20 = {diff(30, 20)}" )

    }
}
```

**Note** :

After I compile the code instead of getting the results I am getting 
result of earlier program, Tried to workout with run config in eclipse
and still same result.

Comment: I recommend to use IntelliJ IDEA, that's great for Kotlin. The guys made Kotlin are the same great guys made IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: may be you need to build that code first and then run

Comment: Thank you very much @Fartab, switching to IntelliJ kept me out of trouble.

Comment: Enjoy it @Dovin ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since in Kotlin we don't have public static void main (no **static** in particular) you have to declare your main function in package scope. i.e outside your class which can be accessed by objects of all other classes within that package. 
So
I think this should work

```
package Test

class DemoFunction {

fun sum(x: Int, y: Int) : Int {
    return x + y;
}

fun diff(a : Float, b: Float) : Float {
    if(a >= b)
        return a - b;
    else
        return 0.0F;
}
}

// main fun
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    var temp=DemoFunction()
    println("Sum of 3 & 5 = " + temp.sum(3, 5))
    println("Difference of 30 & 20 = "+temp.diff(30.toFloat(), 20.toFloat()) )


}
```